# Reddit API by_id request issues

Tags: reddit

I am attempting to send a batch of link ids to the reddit api. A few of my id's are not coming back in the response. Also, some of the posts in the results were not in the original requests. Am I doing something wrong with my request?

https://snap.apigee.com/W5wmLi

If you specifically look for this id `t3_195m70` it is in the request, but not in the response. There are 25 id's in the request and 25 in the response.

I am baffled.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 25 id's in the request and 25 in the response.

There are 44 ids in the request. reddit by default limits your requests to 25 items. The limit can be extended up to 100 if you add `?limit=100` to the end of the URL. If you need to process more than 100 items, you need to make multiple requests.

> Also, some of the posts in the results were not in the original requests

That does not appear to be the case.